# HTML textfield with suggested keywords onclick to input type text field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I found a code to get suggested keywords and fixed it a little bit but I am a PHP-guy so I have been trying the entire day to fix the following problem:

There is a textarea in HTML with a text editor function from CKeditor, while you write some text it shows you some suggested keywords for the search engine metatags. Obviously not all keywords will be good for you so you can just click on any of these keywords to choose the keywords you really want.

The problem is that if you check the demo on Fiddle, you will notice that if you click to select the first keyword if works ok, the keyword gets auto-filled in another text input to be saved in MySQL (because I need it so) but now if you click to select other keywords lets say number 10 it should only select this keyword but nope, it just take all 10 keywords and if you select keyword 5 it select 5 keywords.

Here is the part of the code with the problem:

```
    if (TextGrab != "") {
      var keyCSV = KeyDensityShow(TextGrab, 11, 3);
      var KeysArr = keyCSV.toString().split(',');
      var item, items = '';
      var previousKeys = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < KeysArr.length; i++) {
        item = '';
        var key = KeysArr[i];
        previousKeys.push(key);
        item = item + '<b>' + key + "</b></button>&nbsp;";
        i++;
        item = '<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(\'thebox\').value=\'' + previousKeys.join(', ') + '\';"><span class="badge">' + KeysArr[i] + "</span>&nbsp;" + item;
        items = items + item;
      }
      $('#KWdensity').html(items);
    }
  }
});
```

and the HTML is:

```
<input type="text" id="thebox" value="">
```

Please take a look at the demo on Fiddle.

Any idea how to fix that?

The code is simple javascript and I have JQuery installed if needed

[Demo on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/752jspdg/1/)